# Raspberry Pi Connection closed SSH

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I just bought a raspberry Pi 3. I am trying to run it but first it wrote `connection refused` on ssh attempt. After I ran the `raspi-config` and enabled the ssh I now get a `Connection closed by 192.168.0.31`. When I scan the ports on that machine the `22/tcp` is open (using `nmap`).
What could be the problem?

Comment: does the target machine have ssh-server installed?

Comment: the port 22 is open. raspberry pi itself comes with ssh-server, doesn't it?

Answer (score 8):

I just found this solution, now the ssh works:

```
sudo rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same problem.
So I tried the following solution.
1. Try to create an empty **SSH** file without any extension in RPI bootable file.
2. Try to execute `sudo systemctl enable ssh
sudo systemctl start ssh` during boot time, using `.bashrc` file